# Why is this IIF comparison failing

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I have to work with a database that returns string data that is both alpha characters but also uses numeric characters.  For example 1 record may return the string"1000" the next may return the string "blah"  All alpha strings will always be "Blah"

When a numeric string is returned I want to format it as currency and if it is alpha show "Blah".

This is what I have tried and it kind of works???

```
 =IIf(IsNumeric(First(Fields!MyField.Value, "DataSet1")), FormatCurrency(First(Fields!MyField.Value, "DataSet1")) ,"Blah")
```

If the MyField value is a string that is numeric such as "1000" it is formatted on the report as $1,000.00. However if the MyField value is "blah", the report shows "ERROR"

Can anyone explain why I am seeing this strange behavior?

Thanks
Perry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both conditions of an `IIf` expression are always evaluated so the problem occurs when `FormatCurrency("blah")` is evaluated even if `IsNumeric("blah")` return `False`.

You can solve this problem using the same logic in a [custom code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156028.aspx) where you can use a full `If/Then/Else` code.